# how to implement cache in react-native-video

Tags: react-native

How do we implement caching in [react-native-video](https://github.com/drivetribe/react-native-video/)? Basically, when a video is currently streaming from a network resource, how do we save the video somewhere, and then retrieve it when the same resource is access. What is the best approach for this?

Comment: could you find a solution for caching videos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best approach that i would refer you is using react-native-fetch-blob, you can implement it like this:

```
const RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob').default;

const {
    fs
} = RNFetchBlob;

const baseCacheDir = fs.dirs.CacheDir + '/videocache';

//call the downloadVideo function
  downloadVideo('http://....',baseCacheDir) 
//Function to download a file..
const activeDownloads = {};
function downloadVideo(fromUrl, toFile) {
    // use toFile as the key
        activeDownloads[toFile] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            RNFetchBlob
                .config({path: toFile})
                .fetch('GET', fromUrl)
                .then(res => {
                    if (Math.floor(res.respInfo.status / 100) !== 2) {
                        throw new Error('Failed to successfully download video');
                    }
                    resolve(toFile);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    return deleteFile(toFile)
                        .then(() => reject(err));
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    // cleanup
                    delete activeDownloads[toFile];
                });
        });
    return activeDownloads[toFile];
}

//To delete a file..

function deleteFile(filePath) {
    return fs.stat(filePath)
        .then(res => res && res.type === 'file')
        .then(exists => exists && fs.unlink(filePath)) //if file exist
        .catch((err) => {
            // swallow error to always resolve
        });
}
```

Cheers:)

Comment: I'm a little confused.... where/ how do you assign activeDownloads?
also, how do you deleteFile? this doesn't seem like a complete solution

Comment: activeDownloads array is for you to keep track of cached data file path so that you can unlink if needed ... please go through the edits after 18 mins..

Comment: Ok, now it makes more sense :) but shouldn't there be a specific key per cachekey?

Comment: yeah there is a key activeDownloads[toFile], toFile is a key in activeDownloads object..

Comment: but the way you are calling it it seems as the key is always the same key

Comment: thats just to explain... const baseCacheDir = fs.dirs.CacheDir + '/videocache'; in this line of code you can append index to make the key unique...like this: const baseCacheDir = fs.dirs.CacheDir + '/videocache' + index;

Comment: Should make the cache key the url.  Two different videos with the same name could overwrite one another.

Comment: Will it work for HLS video too? And it will play video without internet?